# Using SSL cert for my IIS website confusion issue

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

So I am new to using SSL certs on websites and have some questions..

1. If I get a SSL cert I can use it on my main production web box and a clone failover box correct, I don't need to get two different PFX keys or pay for two?
2. I have two sites like this in IIS7.

   a. www.kylesite.com
   b. account.kylesite.com

They both need https but when I assign the SSL ceftificate in the http binding of the site it gives me this and I don't know what to make of it or if I can use this same cert for my main site and subdomain site..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes you can export to PFX (include the private key), and import into a new box.

2) You need a unique IP:PORT combo in order to bind IIS to an SSL certificate.